# Unable To Execute Callback of chrome.storage.local.set In popup.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a simple chrome extension that contains an HTML popup (`popup.html`) with an associated `popup.js` file. When a user clicks a button in `popup.js`, I would like to retrieve and set a value using `chrome.storage.local.get` and `chrome.storage.local.set`. After this process, I would like to notify the user that the update is complete (with some simple jQuery). However, I placed this jQuery update code inside the callback of my `chrome.storage.local.set`, and when the button is clicked, the dynamic update never occurs, thus, I suspect that the callback never executed. I believe this is so because I placed the notification snippet inside the `chrome.storage.local.get` callback, and was able to display the proper message:

`popup.html`:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test Extensio</title>
      <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='popup.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <button class='get-notified'>Run Test</button>
       <div class='update-display'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.get-notified', function(){
       chrome.storage.local.get(['counter'], function(result){
          var new_count = result.counter === undefined ? 1 : parseInt(result.counter)+1
          chrome.storage.local.set({'counter':new_count}, function(){
             $('.update-display').html(`The count is: ${new_count}`)
             //this is never executed
          });
       });
    });
});
```

With the code sample above, the counter message is never displayed. However, when I remove `chrome.storage.local.set` and run the update inside the callback of `chrome.storage.local.get`, it does work:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['counter'], function(result){
    var new_count = result.counter === undefined ? 1 : parseInt(result.counter)+1
    $('.update-display').html(`The count is: ${new_count}`)
    //this works
});
```

Why is it that `$('.update-display').html(...)` works in the first callback, the callback of `chrome.storage.local.get`, but not the inner callback of `chrome.storage.local.set`?

My `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test extension",
  "description": "A Description coming soon",
  "version": "2.0",
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "/images/icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "background" : {
     "scripts" : ["jquery.min.js", "popup.js"]
   },
   "permissions": [
   "storage",
   "activeTab",
   "declarativeContent",
   "webNavigation",
   "unlimitedStorage",
   "tabs",
   "cookies",
   "webRequest",
   "webRequestBlocking",
   "http://*/",
   "https://*/",
   "http://fonts.googleapis.com/",
   "https://fonts.googleapis.com/"

 ],

   "web_accessible_resources": ["popup.html"],
  ....
 }
```

Does anyone know why this baffling behavior might occur? Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

For those interested, I discovered the problem: I added a `window.close()` above my `chrome.storage.local.get` that would inevitably close the popup after the user clicked the button a certain number of times. I simply moved the `window.close` inside my original callback, and the `chrome.storage.local.set` worked fine:

```
/*this did not work
if (somecondition){
    window.close();
}
*/
chrome.storage.local.get(['counter'], function(result){
   var new_count = result.counter === undefined ? 1 : parseInt(result.counter)+1
    chrome.storage.local.set({'counter':new_count}, function(){
        $('.update-display').html(`The count is: ${new_count}`)
        //this worked
        if (somecondition){
            window.close();
        }
    });
 });
```